# Downloading a Git LFS file from GitLab instance

Tags: github, gitlab, git-lfs

I am working on a project which requires downloading some files from the GitLab repository. I am working on a self-managed GitLab instance.

There is no problem with using v4 API to download standard files with:

```
https://{instance}/api/v4/projects/:id/repository/files/:file_path/raw
```

On the other hand, I am struggling to download LFS files. The same request used on the LFS file returns:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:{sha}
size {size}
```

I've been trying to follow this tutorial:

https://gist.github.com/fkraeutli/66fa741d9a8c2a6a238a01d17ed0edc5

but I am stuck on this part:

```
https://github.com/{organization}/{repository}.git/info/lfs/objects/batch
```

I am not sure what `organization` and `repository` should be. I am also unsure if it is the correct URL to do so since I am using GitLab not GitHub.

If someone has struggled with a similar problem, I'd be glad to hear some advice. Cheers!

Comment: When using Git-LFS, *Git* does not have the large file. Git never *sees* the large file: the LFS wrappers (which are not part of Git) *hide* the large file *from* Git. They store the large files separately, on a separate server, and trick Git. So nothing you do with normal Git will work at all here: you *must* use some sort of bypass mechanism. The details will depend on the server, and I have no idea what the GitLab details are, but the GitHub method probably won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The download process has evolved with [GitLab 16.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/07/22/gitlab-16-2-released/#improve-git-lfs-download-performance) (July 2023)

> ### Improve Git LFS download performance
>
> For instances which store LFS objects in object storage without [proxy download enabled](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/object_storage.html#proxy-download), GitLab now processes LFS requests in bulk. This dramatically improves the performance of downloading a large number of LFS objects.
>
> Previously, due to how LFS objects were fetched, GitLab created many very small requests which checked user permissions and redirected to the object stored externally. This had the potential to cause significant load and a reduction in performance.
>
> With this fix, we have reduced load on the primary GitLab instance and provided a faster download experience for our users.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/lfs/index.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/413684).